# How can I capture an unsigned value without casting?

Tags: c++, types, casting, signed

How can I **capture** an `unsigned` value without casting?

I am writing a simple program to calculate the LCF and the GCD of an array of numbers. In order to properly calculate them, the numbers should be always positive intergers, for I which chose the type "`unsigned long long int`". However, I still did not find a way to prevent the user to enter a negative value **without** casting.

Whenever I use `std::cin >> variable`, the program allows the user to enter a negative number. In case of unsigned values, the number will be the range-minus-value of the size of type. In case of `unsigned short` interger, if a user enters `-5`, the value stored in the variable will be `65.531`.

Here is the part of the code I am trying to improve:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

typedef unsigned long long int ulli;

 /* many lines of code, variables already declared */

// array_list_of_numbers is of type UNsigned long long int
// var_verify_if_negative is of type signed long long int

    cout << "Please inform the numbers." << endl;
    for ( iterador1 = 0 ; iterador1 < size_of_the_list ; ++iterador1){
        cout << "Please, inform  number  "<< iterador1+1 << ": ";
        cin >> var_verify_if_negative;
        while (var_verify_if_negative <= 0){
            cout << "Number must be equal or greater than 1!" << endl;
            cout << "Try again: ";
            cin >> var_verify_if_negative;  
        /*end while*/}
        array_list_of_numbers[iterador1] = (ulli)var_verify_if_negative; // << here is the casting 
    /*end for*/}
```

However, if I use casting of a signed variable, there is no point of using unsigned data type at all. It would be better to declare the variables already as signed and perform the check.

The original code was:

```
cout << "Please inform the numbers." << endl;
    for ( iterador1 = 0 ; iterador1 < size_of_the_list ; ++iterador1){
        cout << "Please, inform  number  "<< iterador1+1 << ": ";
        cin >>  array_list_of_numbers[iterador1];
    /*end for*/}
```

Which allows wrong input.
How can I test if a user entered a signed value using `std::cin` ?

Comment: Don't use an unsigned type.  Just because the number can't be negative doesn't mean you should use an unsigned type.  Use unsigned for bit manipulation and signed for everything else, unless you *really* need that extra bit.  If you use a signed type it's trivial to check if you get a negative number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply read a (signed) long and refuse it when its negative and use it otherwise ?

If you really need the full range of an unsigned long you would need to read a string first, check if it starts with a '-' (and refuse) and convert to unsigned long otherwise.

Comment: The idea was to use the full range of unsigned LLI . Your idea to use strings seems to be the correct approach to solve this problem, even though really huge numbers would also inflict error in the program.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no specific extractor which would refuse signed integers for standard stream, instead, signed integer is converted to unsigned value (which is actually undefined behavior for negative numbers).

However, your whole approach is somewhat flawed. If you want to disallow numbers which are less than 0, the best you can do is to actually accept signed integers, and than check the number to be greater than zero and report error (and refuse the input) when it is not.

Answer (score 1):

The best case scenario would have been for the stream extractor to report failure when a negative number is entered when the expected type is an unsigned type.

```
unsigned int num;
while ( !(in >> num) )
{
   std::cerr << "Wrong input. Try again...";
}
```

However, the standard specifies that it's OK to enter negative number even when the expected type is an unsigned type.

When the type is an unsigned type, the standard library uses the `%u` format specifier in the core conversion logic. From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get:

> If the type of `v` is unsigned, will use conversion specifier `%u`

Now, if you look at how the standard library deals with `%u` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf#Parameters), the conversion is performed by `strtoul`.

From [`strtoul` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul):

> If the minus sign was part of the input sequence, the numeric value calculated from the sequence of digits is negated as if by unary minus in the result type, which applies unsigned integer wraparound rules.

Your best bet is to read into a signed type and make sure it is a non-negative number before proceeding to use it.